# Null coalescing operator giving Specified cast is not valid int to short

Tags: c#, .net, casting, null-coalescing-operator

Does anyone know why the last one doesn't work?

```
object nullObj = null;
short works1 = (short) (nullObj ?? (short) 0);
short works2 = (short) (nullObj ?? default(short));
short works3 = 0;
short wontWork = (short) (nullObj ?? 0); //Throws: Specified cast is not valid
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `0` is an int, which is implicitly converted to an object (boxed), and you can't unbox a boxed int directly to a short.  This will work:

```
short s = (short)(int)(nullObj ?? 0);
```

A boxed `T` (where `T` is a non-nullable value type, of course) may be unboxed only to `T` or `T?`.

Comment: [Representation and Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) explains why this is necessary (i.e., why this isn't done automatically with only 1 cast).

Answer (score 5):

The result of the null-coalescing operator in the last line is a boxed `int`. You're then trying to unbox that to `short`, which fails at execution time in the way you've shown.

It's like you've done this:

```
object x = 0;
short s = (short) x;
```

The presence of the null-coalescing operator is a bit of a red-herring here.